# How would you give an Outline View alternating row colors?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I know there is a check box for it in IB but that only gives you the colors White and Blue. How would I make it so that it used different colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this code to it,

```
// RGB values for stripe color (light blue)
#define STRIPE_RED   (237.0 / 255.0)
#define STRIPE_GREEN (243.0 / 255.0)
#define STRIPE_BLUE  (254.0 / 255.0)
static NSColor *sStripeColor = nil;

    @implementation …

// This is called after the table background is filled in,
// but before the cell contents are drawn.
// We override it so we can do our own light-blue row stripes a la iTunes.
- (void) highlightSelectionInClipRect:(NSRect)rect {
    [self drawStripesInRect:rect];
    [super highlightSelectionInClipRect:rect];
}

// This routine does the actual blue stripe drawing,
// filling in every other row of the table with a blue background
// so you can follow the rows easier with your eyes.
- (void) drawStripesInRect:(NSRect)clipRect {
    NSRect stripeRect;
    float fullRowHeight = [self rowHeight] + [self intercellSpacing].height;
    float clipBottom = NSMaxY(clipRect);
    int firstStripe = clipRect.origin.y / fullRowHeight;
    if (firstStripe % 2 == 0)
        firstStripe++;   // we're only interested in drawing the stripes
                         // set up first rect
    stripeRect.origin.x = clipRect.origin.x;
    stripeRect.origin.y = firstStripe * fullRowHeight;
    stripeRect.size.width = clipRect.size.width;
    stripeRect.size.height = fullRowHeight;
    // set the color
    if (sStripeColor == nil)
        sStripeColor = [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:STRIPE_RED
                           green:STRIPE_GREEN
                           blue:STRIPE_BLUE
                           alpha:1.0] retain];
    [sStripeColor set];
    // and draw the stripes
    while (stripeRect.origin.y < clipBottom) {
        NSRectFill(stripeRect);
        stripeRect.origin.y += fullRowHeight * 2.0;
    }
}
```

But I do not know how to Sub-class NSOutlineView. Could some one tell me how I could sub-class NSOutline View?

Comment: Note: This is answered in the related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992389/subclassing-nsoutlineview